# Scroll Left to Right on MAX7219 Display

Tags: arduino-uno, string, display, max7219

For scrolling from `left to right` (**Arabic** letters) I need a function to print **words/sentences** on the MAX7219 display. [By `setpixel(x, y)` function]

I did a lot of searching and my efforts failed. I found the [following example](https://github.com/bartoszbielawski/LEDMatrixDriver/blob/master/examples/MarqueeText/MarqueeText.ino) but I couldn't change it. By default this example scrolls from `right to left`. (I need scroll from left to right.)

```
#include <LEDMatrixDriver.hpp>
const uint8_t LEDMATRIX_CS_PIN = 9;

// Number of 8x8 segments you are connecting
const int LEDMATRIX_SEGMENTS = 4;
const int LEDMATRIX_WIDTH    = LEDMATRIX_SEGMENTS * 8;

// The LEDMatrixDriver class instance
LEDMatrixDriver lmd(LEDMATRIX_SEGMENTS, LEDMATRIX_CS_PIN);

// Marquee text
char text[] = "** LED MATRIX DEMO! ** (1234567890) ++ \"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\" ++ <$%/=?'.@,> --";

// Marquee speed (lower nubmers = faster)
const int ANIM_DELAY = 30;

void setup() {
  // init the display
  lmd.setEnabled(true);
  lmd.setIntensity(2);   // 0 = low, 10 = high
}

int x=0, y=0;   // start top left

// This is the font definition. You can use http://gurgleapps.com/tools/matrix to create your own font or sprites.
// If you like the font feel free to use it. I created it myself and donate it to the public domain.
byte font[95][8] = { {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, // SPACE
                     {0x10,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x18,0x18}, // EXCL
                     {0x28,0x28,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}, // QUOT
                     {0x00,0x0a,0x7f,0x14,0x28,0xfe,0x50,0x00}, // #
                     {0x10,0x38,0x54,0x70,0x1c,0x54,0x38,0x10}, // $
                     {0x00,0x60,0x66,0x08,0x10,0x66,0x06,0x00}, // %
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, // &
                     {0x00,0x10,0x18,0x18,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00}, // '
                     {0x02,0x04,0x08,0x08,0x08,0x08,0x08,0x04}, // (
                     {0x40,0x20,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x20}, // )
                     {0x00,0x10,0x54,0x38,0x10,0x38,0x54,0x10}, // *
                     {0x00,0x08,0x08,0x08,0x7f,0x08,0x08,0x08}, // +
                     {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x18,0x18,0x08}, // COMMA
                     {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x7e,0x00,0x00,0x00}, // -
                     {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x06,0x06}, // DOT
                     {0x00,0x04,0x04,0x08,0x10,0x20,0x40,0x40}, // /
                     {0x00,0x38,0x44,0x4c,0x54,0x64,0x44,0x38}, // 0
                     {0x04,0x0c,0x14,0x24,0x04,0x04,0x04,0x04}, // 1
                     {0x00,0x30,0x48,0x04,0x04,0x38,0x40,0x7c}, // 2
                     {0x00,0x38,0x04,0x04,0x18,0x04,0x44,0x38}, // 3
                     {0x00,0x04,0x0c,0x14,0x24,0x7e,0x04,0x04}, // 4
                     {0x00,0x7c,0x40,0x40,0x78,0x04,0x04,0x38}, // 5
                     {0x00,0x38,0x40,0x40,0x78,0x44,0x44,0x38}, // 6
                     {0x00,0x7c,0x04,0x04,0x08,0x08,0x10,0x10}, // 7
                     {0x00,0x3c,0x44,0x44,0x38,0x44,0x44,0x78}, // 8
                     {0x00,0x38,0x44,0x44,0x3c,0x04,0x04,0x78}, // 9
                     {0x00,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x00,0x18,0x18,0x00}, // :
                     {0x00,0x18,0x18,0x00,0x00,0x18,0x18,0x08}, // ;
                     {0x00,0x10,0x20,0x40,0x80,0x40,0x20,0x10}, // <
                     {0x00,0x00,0x7e,0x00,0x00,0xfc,0x00,0x00}, // =
                     {0x00,0x08,0x04,0x02,0x01,0x02,0x04,0x08}, // >
                     {0x00,0x38,0x44,0x04,0x08,0x10,0x00,0x10}, // ?
                     {0x00,0x30,0x48,0xba,0xba,0x84,0x78,0x00}, // @
                     {0x00,0x1c,0x22,0x42,0x42,0x7e,0x42,0x42}, // A
                     {0x00,0x78,0x44,0x44,0x78,0x44,0x44,0x7c}, // B
                     {0x00,0x3c,0x44,0x40,0x40,0x40,0x44,0x7c}, // C
                     {0x00,0x7c,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x44,0x78}, // D
                     {0x00,0x78,0x40,0x40,0x70,0x40,0x40,0x7c}, // E
                     {0x00,0x7c,0x40,0x40,0x78,0x40,0x40,0x40}, // F
                     {0x00,0x3c,0x40,0x40,0x5c,0x44,0x44,0x78}, // G
                     {0x00,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x7e,0x42,0x42,0x42}, // H
                     {0x00,0x7c,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x7e}, // I
                     {0x00,0x7e,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x02,0x04,0x38}, // J
                     {0x00,0x44,0x48,0x50,0x60,0x50,0x48,0x44}, // K
                     {0x00,0x40,0x40,0x40,0x40,0x40,0x40,0x7c}, // L
                     {0x00,0x82,0xc6,0xaa,0x92,0x82,0x82,0x82}, // M
                     {0x00,0x42,0x42,0x62,0x52,0x4a,0x46,0x42}, // N
                     {0x00,0x3c,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x44,0x38}, // O
                     {0x00,0x78,0x44,0x44,0x48,0x70,0x40,0x40}, // P
                     {0x00,0x3c,0x42,0x42,0x52,0x4a,0x44,0x3a}, // Q
                     {0x00,0x78,0x44,0x44,0x78,0x50,0x48,0x44}, // R
                     {0x00,0x38,0x40,0x40,0x38,0x04,0x04,0x78}, // S
                     {0x00,0x7e,0x90,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10}, // T
                     {0x00,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x3e}, // U
                     {0x00,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x42,0x44,0x28,0x10}, // V
                     {0x80,0x82,0x82,0x92,0x92,0x92,0x94,0x78}, // W
                     {0x00,0x42,0x42,0x24,0x18,0x24,0x42,0x42}, // X
                     {0x00,0x44,0x44,0x28,0x10,0x10,0x10,0x10}, // Y
                     {0x00,0x7c,0x04,0x08,0x7c,0x20,0x40,0xfe}, // Z
                      // (the font does not contain any lower case letters. you can add your own.)
                  };    // {}, //


void loop()
{
    // Draw the text to the current position
    int len = strlen(text);
    drawString(text, len, x, 0);
    // In case you wonder why we don't have to call lmd.clear() in every loop: The font has a opaque (black) background...

    // Toggle display of the new framebuffer
    lmd.display();

    // Wait to let the human read the display
    delay(ANIM_DELAY);

    // Advance to next coordinate
    if( --x < len * -8 ) {
        x = LEDMATRIX_WIDTH;
    }
}


/**
 * This function draws a string of the given length to the given position.
 */
void drawString(char* text, int len, int x, int y )
{
  for( int idx = 0; idx < len; idx ++ )
  {
    int c = text[idx] - 32;

    // stop if char is outside visible area
    if( x + idx * 8  > LEDMATRIX_WIDTH )
      return;

    // only draw if char is visible
    if( 8 + x + idx * 8 > 0 )
      drawSprite( font[c], x + idx * 8, y, 8, 8 );
  }
}

/**
 * This draws a sprite to the given position using the width and height supplied (usually 8x8)
 */
void drawSprite( byte* sprite, int x, int y, int width, int height )
{
  // The mask is used to get the column bit from the sprite row
  byte mask = B10000000;

  for( int iy = 0; iy < height; iy++ )
  {
    for( int ix = 0; ix < width; ix++ )
    {
      lmd.setPixel(x + ix, y + iy, (bool)(sprite[iy] & mask ));

      // shift the mask by one pixel to the right
      mask = mask >> 1;
    }

    // reset column mask
    mask = B10000000;
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The scrolling from left to right, the printing from right to left or printing arabic letters?

Comment: @chrisl Change example above and scroll from left to right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To scroll in the opposite direction, change this if statement:

```
if( --x < len * -8 ) {
    x = LEDMATRIX_WIDTH;
}
```

to this:

```
if( ++x > LEDMATRIX_WIDTH+len*8 ){
    x = 0;
}
```

`x` (the start position of the text) is now incremented instead of decremented, until the whole text (consisting of `len*8` pixels in x direction) is out of the display, where it then gets reset to zero.

This assumes, that the printing of the arabic letters is done from right to left (You might want to implement this, when working with arabic text). The function in the example prints always from left to right, so you need to use this code:

```
if( ++x > LEDMATRIX_WIDTH ){
    x = -len*8;
}
```

since in this case the text will not be visible in the moment, that the position is over the matrix width.

Comment: Thanks @chrisl, I modified the code as you said (`if statement`), But no text is displayed, Please see the [video](https://youtu.be/pbQTnB0pi9I), In the first phase I want to scroll the same English `text variable` from left to right.

Comment: Ok, I corrected an error in the last code bit, that you need to use. Of course the text position needs to be reset to the corresponding negative value, so that the right end of the text will scroll into the display. Sorry for that error.

Comment: Thanks @chrisl, Everything is okay.

Comment: You can use the MD Parola library which has a setting to change the direction.
PA_SCROLL_RIGHT or PA_SCROLL_LEFT.

Comment: Thanks @tavis , I'll test. Of course, I need a library that has `setpixel(x, y)` function.